# Customer gets to PayPal checkout page but not paying

Tags: payment, purchase, visitors

I have an e-commerce store where I sell templates, I have been noticing that my customers/visitors usually gets to the PayPal checkout page but not paying. Well, they can't get to that page if they don't click the buy button (which temporary stores the item into the order table)... it means they are willing to buy the template but somehow they just don't complete the purchase (which is from PayPal checkout).

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: This should be pretty obvious, but does your store reflects the final price without having to click buy? Maybe they are just clicking because they want to know how much that would cost, but your site is not providing this information in a clear enough way.

Comment: Yes it does boldly, it is a template store just like themeforest - it is just one price for a template right beside the template itself.

Comment: Shine: Ok, disregard my comment. ;-)

Comment: Can you link the site?

Comment: @Bulwersator ... what do you mean link the site?

Comment: Can you tell if the customers go back to a different page on your site, or if they abandon the whole thing?

Comment: "I have an e-commerce store" - so link it, maybe there is something wrong with this site.

Comment: @vincebowdren ... I cant really tell what they do after the return from PayPal. All I know is sometimes I get this uncompleted orders and no order was made afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: most of they are not really interested in **pay** your product, but just *like to visit your site*. The rest of users maybe are really trying to buy.

### Long answer

You have two types of visitors who click to buy: that who want to buy, and that who will never buy (for this visit). Both are common, but you are interested on fist one.

For who is interested in buy your product, you should try to see the whys. Since your questions is just mentioning the payment method, few good motivations for interested clients are:

- **Do not know how to use your payment method. Try to make it more simple, or give options**
- **Do not trust your payment method, or maybe your site who point to the payment method. *Try to be more professional***
- **Some people tryed to pay, but they payment was refused and they leave your site. Try to give more payment options or take they e-mail for reminder for the future**

Keep in mind that like in real world, people go inside shops, see products, but do not buy. On internet this is more common. Some e-commerces show that is less than 5-1% of the visitors that really will buy on your site.

Comment: Thanks Emerson for the suggestions, I am aware that there are visitors who might want to buy or just checking out. I personally do think once they click on the buy button which takes them to the PayPal - they are really interested in the product. (I usually see uncompleted orders 1-2 in a day). I will try to add options to the payment method